# Why does tinyurl produce 2 different links for the same URL?

Tags: url, url-shortening

https://tinyurl.com/yx33pj22

https://tinyurl.com/dskmjw8j

These two lines direct me to same page. Why does tinyurl produce 2 different links for the same URL?